# Unable to send email using Sendgrid web api

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send email using Sendgrid web API using NodeJs.In my backend code, I am trying to implement when a user successfully get registered a welcome email should be sent to user email.

This is my code below,

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const env = require('dotenv').config();
    const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

    var dburl = process.env.URL;
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    router.use(bodyParser.json());
    router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

    router.post('/users', (req,res) => {

      var data = {

          _id:req.body.id,
          Name:req.body.username,
          Email:req.body.email 
      };

      const msg = {

          to: 'example@gmail.com',
          from: 'test@gmail.com',
          subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
          text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
          html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>'

     };

      MongoClient.connect(dburl,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, (err,client) => {


             if(err){

                console.log('Unable to connect with database'.red +err);
             }
             else{

                client.db("Example").collection("Users").findOne({_id:req.body.id},function(err,user) {

                          if(err){

                            console.log("Error:".red +err);
                          }
                          if(user){

                            res.send("User exists");
                          }
                          else{

                            var collection = client.db("Example").collection("Users");

                            collection.insertOne(data,(err,resp) => {

                                 if(err){

                                    console.log("Insertion error".red +err);

                                 }
                                 else{

                                    res.send("User created");
                                    sgMail.send(msg,(err) => {

                                            if(err){
                                             console.log("Error",err);
                                          }else{

                                             console.log("Mail sent");
                                             }

                                       });
                                 }


                            });

                         }

                           client.close();
                });

             }

         });  

     });

   module.exports = router;
```

After registering user it email is not sending to the registered user.
Someone, please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any logs from send method?
You can get the log by call back such as sgMail.send(msg, function(err){})

Comment: I tried your solution but after getting response User created it is showing nothing in logs it seems that email is not sending.

Comment: Did you check the spam directory in mail inbox?

Comment: Yes ,there is nothing in spam.

Comment: PLease take a look on mail sending part I have updated my post.

Comment: What's the message returned by your last console.log?

Comment: Now emails are sending but why they are going in spam folder.